# Stream audio from PC to Raspberry Pi in realtime?

Tags: audio, wireless

I want to create a wireless headset project (just for fun). I want to be able to power my Raspberry Pi through USB, then connect my PC to the Raspberry Pi. All the sounds coming from my PC should be played back by the Raspberry Pi. By doing this, I can have a wireless pair of headphones.

So far I have tried pulseaudio, but it had a really long delay and the quality was really bad. The PC I will be using is on a wired gigabit connection, and the Raspberry Pi will be as well.

Can anyone help me here? I need to know the fastest and best way to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright I'm posting an update. I tried with Shairport and it works brilliantly. I can play music just fine, but when I go watch videos, I can hear the voice being a few milliseconds (NOT A LOT) behind. But so far it's working great. I wish I could eliminate the delay completely, but I just don't think that's possible.

Shairplay is the way to go I think.

http://lifehacker.com/5978594/turn-a-raspberry-pi-into-an-airplay-receiver-for-streaming-music-in-your-living-room

Comment: Yea shairplay is good. Please mark you answer as accepted if it resolved your problem.

Comment: I can do that in two days, but I still feel like the delay should be closer to none. I mean, would it work better if I looked into bluetooth for instance? Update on how my headset looks now: http://i.imgur.com/btEH6ia.jpg - I'm kinda proud, lmao.

Comment: Bluetooth may have rubbish sound, especially if you have a good sound system hooked up. Plus, its a bit more of a pain for sharing. The delay.. maybe you can delay your video a bit to compensate, that's all I can suggest. (VLC can do this) To bad shairplay doesn't support video though. You can have a look into DLNA also. Put it on the Pi DLNA server and use something like allcast to play your audio from phone or similar on PC

Comment: I see. I hear good reviews about headphones like the Momentum 2.0 from Sennheiser (Bluetooth 4.0). I could get rid of the delay.. perhaps. But no, these are just some Steelseries Siberia V2 headphones. Sound quality with Shairplay is stunningly good. I can't hear a difference.

Comment: Yea shairplay will be good. Its basically the exact data being pushed to the Pi and piped into omx or asound or something. I updated my comment but DLNA wont help here. I didnt realise you wanted a remote headset thing. The only option is to delay the video on your PC. :(

Comment: I don't want video though. I only want audio ;)

Comment: Yea I realise that, thats why DLNA isnt for you. shairplay is the most stable and easy to use. Like I suggested. You need to offset the video to be delayed about -250ms max maybe, or make the audio playback faster +250ms - Depends on the latency of your WiFi, and bitrate of audio.

Comment: Oh right like that, yep. It's definitely a lot lower than 250 ms. Sometimes as low as 10ms even. Depends on the WiFi signal to be honest. But I can't slow everything down, as I'm just mirroring my whole system's sound and not just from VLC or whatever.

Comment: 10ms? :) that's hardly noticeable, thats like faster than GSM! :)). Yea, at least for movies you can slow it down to adjust it. Windows sounds, like games.. yea. Not possible really.